# Single backend with multiple APIs

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a single backend defined, for this example named `myserver` with a runtime url `https://myserver.com`. Also, I have "Authorization credentials" set for this backend:
The header `x-custom-header` is added with a secret value. Every request needs to provide this header.

My backend provides the following endpoints:

```
GET https://myserver.com/Devices
GET https://myserver.com/Devices/device-1
POST https://myserver.com/Devices
Get https://myserver.com/Weather?location=Vienna
...
```

Here comes the problem:
I want to provide multiple APIs specific for the data:

- Devices Api with API URL suffix `Devices`:

  - `https://mycompany-apim.azure-api.net/Devices`
- Weather Api with API URL suffix `Weather`:

  - `https://mycompany-apim.azure-api.net/Weather`

For some reason, I don't understand how I can achieve that with only a single backend without too much configuration hassle. I have configured `<set-backend-service backend-id="myserver" />` but that obviously does not correctly resolve `https://mycompany-apim.azure-api.net/Devices` to `GET https://myserver.com/Devices` but only to `GET https://myserver.com/`.

Some solutions that might work:

- Define a backend for each API. E.g. backend `myserver-devices` with the base url `https://myserver.com/Devices`

  - Problem: I don't want to have X backends configured the same way just with a different url ending.
- Configure an `rewrite-uri` policy for each endpoint in each API.

  - Problem: Obviously, this would be even more configuration overhead.

**Are there alternatives?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating one API e.g. `73219639` and the required operations:

[image]

It's important that each APIM operation has the same path e.g. `/Devices`:
https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/Devices -> https://myserver.com/Devices

This is the simple working yaml:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: '73219639'
  description: ''
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: 'https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net'
paths:
  /Devices:
    post:
      summary: Devices
      description: Devices
      operationId: post-devices
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
    get:
      summary: Devices
      description: Devices
      operationId: get-devices
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
  /Weather:
    get:
      summary: Weather
      description: Weather
      operationId: get-weather
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
components:
  securitySchemes:
    apiKeyHeader:
      type: apiKey
      name: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key
      in: header
    apiKeyQuery:
      type: apiKey
      name: subscription-key
      in: query
security:
  - apiKeyHeader: []
  - apiKeyQuery: []
```

Configure the Backend in the `All operations` policy with an existing `backend`:

[image: Backend]

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service backend-id="myserver-com" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Do not change/modify any other policy. It's working with the default ones.

**GET Devices - Test:**

HTTP request

GET https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/Devices HTTP/1.1
Host: rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true

[image: Request]

Trace: set-backend-service (18.701 ms)

```json
{
    "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
    "oldBackendServiceUrl": "https://rfqapiservicey27itmeb4cf7q.azure-api.net/",
    "newBackendServiceUrl": "https://myserver.com/",
    "request": {
        "url": "https://myserver.com/Devices"
    }
}
```

Trace: forward-request (0.127 ms)

```json
{
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "https://myserver.com/Devices",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "myserver.com"
            },
            {
```

[image: Forward]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but sadly, this is not what I am after. I require multiple APIs for different tags and settings. Also, not all the paths in the APIM and the backend are equal.

Comment: OK, what is the challenge having several APIs? This will also work this way. Why do tags or settings cause issues here?

Comment: Oh wow... looking at your YAML again I realized my mistake: I did not configure the paths in the operations correctly so no mapping was performed and I always got to the base URL of the backend. I thought I *need* multiple APIs to correctly map the operations to my backend but that is done with the operation's url of course. Anyways, I tried your solution and it works. I correctly set up the operations, created the backend and set it for all operations within an API (note that I *could* set the same backend for multiple APIs like I initially intended as well).

Comment: Sadly, I have faced another problem: I would like to set an "API URL suffix" for the API but that does not yield nice URLs for the end-users. E.g. suffix "devices" and the operation "Get Devices" which has the path "/devices" now becomes `https://mycompany-apim.azure-api.net/devices/devices`. The reason I'd like to have a "global" suffix defined for an API is that it prevents adding operations under a different path. The only solution I see here is to either not use the suffix or define multiple backends (which is what I did for now). Maybe I am mixing up "APIs" and "Products" here.

Comment: so you have to change: `paths:  /Devices:` -> `paths:  /:`

Comment: yes, but this requires the backend to have the url `https://myserver.com/devices` which prevents me from re-using the same backend for lets say "weather" operations

Comment: Please add this `<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Api.Path)" copy-unmatched-params="true" /> into `All operations`
`